# Stacked model, of sorts, with regression and classification

Tags: regression, classification, mixed-model, predictive-models, modeling

I'm building a model and have run into a situation that is new to me.

I need to build a model that predicts the likelihood of an event taking place plus the revenue if that event does, in fact, take place. I decided to follow an Expected Value path where I build a regression model for the predicted revenue and a classification model for the probability of the event taking place. I would then calculate the Expected Value of each observation.

My concern is that some of the features of the classification model are already in my regression model, so I'm thinking these are already being taking into consideration. Am I approaching this incorrectly.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can explain why you took this approach? It isn't clear why you didn't choose differently - to model revenue conditional on the classification, for example. More details might help someone answer your question.

Comment: Hi Eric, I chose this simply because I wasn't sure how to tackle this problem. I'm not familiar with building regression models conditional on a classification. Thank you for pointing this out. I'll do some research to see how this works.

Comment: You might look into the flexmix package in R.